# Linked List delete node bug

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list

Can't believe I'm asking this.

I wrote a simple linked list and there seems to be a weird bug I cannot find. Please, help me.

I add `1`, then `2` to the front. Then I delete a node with value `2`, which is the head.

Right before `delete(head, 2);` returns I have `head->data == 1`. But right after the call in main I get `head->value == 0`.
Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct linked_list
{
    int data;
    struct linked_list *next;
} linked_list_t;

void print_list(linked_list_t *head)
{
    linked_list_t *curr = head;
    printf("LIST: ");
    while (curr)
    {
        printf("%d ", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
}

linked_list_t *add_to_front(linked_list_t *head, int data) 
{
    linked_list_t *new = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_t));
    if (!new) exit(1);
    new->next = head;
    new->data = data;
    return new;
}

void delete(linked_list_t *head, int data) 
{
    linked_list_t *current = head;
    linked_list_t *previous = NULL;
    // move current to the position of the node to delete
    while (current != NULL && current->data != data) 
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current)
    {
        if (previous) 
        {
            // if the node to delete is not head
            previous->next = current->next;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the node to delete is head
            head = current->next;
        }
    }
    free(current);
}

int main()
{
    linked_list_t *head = NULL;
    print_list(head);
    // prints "LIST:"
    head = add_to_front(head, 1);
    head = add_to_front(head, 2);
    print_list(head);
    // prints "LIST: 2 1"
    // head->data = 1 just before delete() exits
    delete(head, 2);
    // head->data = 0 right after delete() exits
    print_list(head);
    // prints "LIST: 0 1" instead of "LIST: 1" 
}
```

Comment: Your program segfaults in the 3rd call to `print_list()`.

Comment: @AllanWind where?

Comment: Doesn't the `head` argument in `delete` need to be a double-pointer?

Comment: `curr = curr->next` where curr is a wild pointer.  If you delete the head then you either need to return new head or pass in a **head so you can update it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it could be, but the way I implemented it is also acceptable. I just use the first node as the reference to the entire list

Comment: Hmm... you print out the first element, if it's just a pointer then it's wrong

Comment: @AllanWind I don't see why my `curr` is a wild pointer

Comment: Because you free the head in delete then try to use it in the next print

Comment: In `delete` I set `head = current ->next` which is an allocated pointer for node with value `1`

Comment: C passes arguments by value so you are modifying a copy.  Let me write you up an answer... give me min.

Comment: @AllanWind dang, I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program segfaults in the 3rd and final (pun) call to `print_list()` when the `head` pointer is dereferenced.  `head` still points to the node that was free'ed in the previous call to `delete()`. Arguments in C are passed by value so in `delete()` when you do `head = current->next;` is no effect outside the `delete()` function.  You have two options:

1. Return the new `head` (see below) or
2. Pass in a `**head` so you can update it

(Not fixed) Symbols that end with the suffix `_t` are reserved so avoid using that.  If I `typedef` then I default to using the same name as the `struct`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct linked_list {
    int data;
    struct linked_list *next;
} linked_list_t;

void print_list(linked_list_t *head) {
    printf("LIST:");
    for(linked_list_t *curr = head; curr; curr = curr->next)
        printf(" %d", curr->data);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);

}

linked_list_t *add_to_front(linked_list_t *head, int data) {
    linked_list_t *new = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_t));
    if (!new) exit(1);
    new->next = head;
    new->data = data;
    return new;
}

linked_list_t *delete(linked_list_t *head, int data) {
    linked_list_t *current = head;
    linked_list_t *previous = NULL;
    for(; current && current->data != data; current = current->next)
        previous = current;
    if (current) {
        if (previous) {
            previous->next = current->next;
            free(current);
        } else {
            current = current->next;
            free(head);
            head = current;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    linked_list_t *head = NULL;
    print_list(head);
    head = add_to_front(head, 1);
    head = add_to_front(head, 2);
    print_list(head);
    head = delete(head, 2);
    print_list(head);
}
```

and example run:

```
LIST:
LIST: 2 1
LIST: 1
```

I prefer early return of special cases so I would end up something along these lines:

```
linked_list_t *delete(linked_list_t **head, int data) {
    if(!head)
        return head;
    if(head->data == data) {
        linked_list_t *tmp = head->next;
        free(head);
        return tmp;
    }
    for(linked_list_t *p = head; p->next; p=p->next) {
        if(p->next->data == data) {
            linked_list_t *tmp = p->next->next;
            free(p->next);
            p->next = tmp;
            break; // or not if you want to delete all matching
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. In `delete`, you're *not* returning the *updated* `head` (as you do in `add_to_front`)
2. When you have to update the `head`, you can use `return` for the *updated* `head` value. This is what you're currently doing.
3. Or, you can pass a *double* pointer (e.g. `**head` instead of `*head`).
4. I [highly] recommend a separate list struct. Then, you always pass the same type of pointer, regardless of what the function does. Even with a *singly* linked list, we can have *both* a `head` and a `tail`.
5. With a `tail`, an `add_to_back` needn't traverse the list each time to find the end of the list.
6. Also, with a list, it's easy to extend the list to be a *doubly* linked list (if we so choose later on).

---

Here is a refactored version that uses a separate list struct. I've renamed `linked_list_t` to `linked_node_t` and repurposed `linked_list_t` as a true list struct:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// node control
typedef struct linked_node {
    int data;
    struct linked_node *next;
} linked_node_t;

// list control
typedef struct linked_list {
    linked_node_t *head;
} linked_list_t;

void
print_list(const linked_list_t *list,const char *reason)
{
    linked_node_t *curr = list->head;

    printf("LIST (%s):",reason);
    while (curr) {
        printf("%d ", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void
add_to_front(linked_list_t *list, int data)
{
    linked_node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_t));

    if (!new)
        exit(1);

    new->next = list->head;
    new->data = data;

    // set new head of the list
    list->head = new;
}

void
delete(linked_list_t *list, int data)
{
    linked_node_t *current = list->head;
    linked_node_t *previous = NULL;

    // move current to the position of the node to delete
    while (current != NULL && current->data != data) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current) {
        // if the node to delete is not head
        if (previous)
            previous->next = current->next;

        // if the node to delete is head
        else
            list->head = current->next;
    }

    free(current);
}

int
main(void)
{
    linked_list_t *list = calloc(1,sizeof(*list));

    print_list(list,"empty");

    // prints "LIST:"
    add_to_front(list, 1);
    add_to_front(list, 2);

    // prints "LIST: 2 1"
    print_list(list,"postadd");

    // head->data = 1 just before delete() exits
    delete(list, 2);

    // head->data = 0 right after delete() exits

    // prints "LIST: 0 1" instead of "LIST: 1"
    print_list(list,"postdel");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the [corrected] program output:

```
LIST (empty):
LIST (postadd):2 1
LIST (postdel):1
```

---

Here is a version that has been extended with a `tail` member to allow quick appending to the back of the list:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// node control
typedef struct linked_node {
    int data;
    struct linked_node *next;
} linked_node_t;

// list control
typedef struct linked_list {
    linked_node_t *head;
    linked_node_t *tail;
} linked_list_t;

void
print_list(const linked_list_t *list,const char *reason)
{
    linked_node_t *curr = list->head;

    printf("LIST (%s):",reason);
    while (curr) {
        printf("%d ", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void
add_to_front(linked_list_t *list, int data)
{
    linked_node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_t));

    if (!new)
        exit(1);

    new->next = list->head;
    new->data = data;

    // set new head of the list
    list->head = new;

    // add to empty list
    if (list->tail == NULL)
        list->tail = new;
}

void
add_to_back(linked_list_t *list, int data)
{
    linked_node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_t));

    if (!new)
        exit(1);

    // append to empty list
    if (list->head == NULL)
        list->head = new;

    linked_node_t *tail = list->tail;

    // append to non-empty list
    if (tail != NULL)
        tail->next = new;

    // append to end
    list->tail = new;

    new->next = NULL;
    new->data = data;
}

void
delete(linked_list_t *list, int data)
{
    linked_node_t *current = list->head;
    linked_node_t *previous = NULL;

    // move current to the position of the node to delete
    while (current != NULL && current->data != data) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current) {
        // if the node to delete is not head
        if (previous)
            previous->next = current->next;

        // if the node to delete is head
        else
            list->head = current->next;

        // remove last element of list
        if (current == list->tail)
            list->tail = previous;
    }

    free(current);
}

int
main(void)
{
    linked_list_t *list = calloc(1,sizeof(*list));

    print_list(list,"empty");

    // prints "LIST:"
    add_to_front(list, 1);
    add_to_front(list, 2);

    // prints "LIST: 2 1"
    print_list(list,"postadd");

    // head->data = 1 just before delete() exits
    delete(list, 2);

    // head->data = 0 right after delete() exits

    // prints "LIST: 0 1" instead of "LIST: 1"
    print_list(list,"postdel");

    add_to_front(list, 4);
    add_to_front(list, 5);
    print_list(list,"post4");

    add_to_back(list, 6);
    add_to_back(list, 7);

    print_list(list,"postback");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output for the extended version:

```
LIST (empty):
LIST (postadd):2 1
LIST (postdel):1
LIST (post4):5 4 1
LIST (postback):5 4 1 6 7
```