# Reading a structure in C from file, I can get it to work 99%

Tags: c

I am adding this function, but it doesn't update the real linked list. Unlike the other functions, this is the only one that doesn't update. I can get the info from the file and store it.

I tried to  write an algorithm that will populate the linked list from reading the file. It just doesn't actually save it

Comment: The code you posted is a start. We want an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Comment: You'll need to provide 2 more thing. First is the `write_movie` that serializes what `read_movie` deserializes. Then you'll need to provide the code that creates the linked list. All of this needs to be a minimal test case that shows what you want and what you got.

Comment: Your use of `offsetof` is, well, unusual ... Although it _can_ be done, binary read/write of a struct with embedded pointers can be problematic.

Comment: @CraigEstey I didn't know what else to use to be able to read/write a linked list. I posted the entire code

Comment: You are doing `fread` to the _same_ memory location, namely `x`. You have to use a _different_ address for each record. As it is, you have only _one_ record (that probably links to itself).

Comment: @JeffHolt I added all the code. All the other functions have been extensively tested, just this one doesn't work. I am unsure how to read or write properly, this is just what I came up with with a bit of research and reading.

Comment: @CraigEstey how do I use a different address in a loop situation? Considering or should I be freeing the memory after every loop? Sorry I am pretty new to all of this

Comment: I was able to test that the x was taking in new information and storing it into the current pointer. I was able to print all the different information of it as i iterated through the loop. So the values are being added

Answer (score 1):

Prefaced by the top comments ...

1. In `read_movie`, using `offsetof` is incorrect.
2. All data is read into the *same* memory location: `x`
3. We need to use `malloc` for a new area for each record.

---

Here is a refactored version of `read_movie` (not tested):

```
void
read_movie(struct movie **head)
{
    struct movie *current = *head;
    struct movie *previous = *head;
    struct movie x;

    FILE *infile;

    infile = fopen("movies.bin", "rb");

    if (infile == NULL) {
        printf("\nError opening file!");
        return;
    }

    rewind(infile);

    while (fread(&x, sizeof(x), 1, infile) == 1) {
        current = malloc(sizeof(*current));
        if (current == NULL)
            exit(9);

        *current = x;
        current->next = NULL;

        if (previous != NULL)
            previous->next = current;
        else
            *head = current;

        previous = current;
    }

    fclose(infile);
}
```

---

Rather than using a "double star" pointer, such as `struct movie **head`, I recommend the use of a separate list struct. See my answer: [Linked List delete node bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77545916/5382650) for an example.

Comment: Ah it was the memory allocation issue. I hadn't realized the proper use of fread() when it comes to the memory and properly pointing to current. Thank you so much for your help in diagnosing this issue.